# Which banks have cash-deposit machines in Germany?

Tags: cash, deposits, atm, germany

Which banks in Germany have machines that you can put cash in and it appears on my bank account (opposite of cash withdrawal)?

I am not interested in the kinds that you put the cash in the envelope and put the envelope in the machine and after a few days they open the envelope at the bank and write it on my account. I am looking for the kind of machine that you put individual bills in, the machine recognizes them and instantly (or at least within an hour) makes it available on my bank account.

BTW it would be very helpful for Googling to know how that kind of machine is called in German? In polish it is "wpłatomat". And what is it most often called in English?

Answer (score 2):

This may not answer your question but it may be an alternative.

My credit union credits my account for deposits immediately (ones I make in an envelope).  They view it as a service to their members.  They take the risk that the member could deposit an empty envelope, say they deposited $400, and then withdraw the money.

There may be banks in your country that do business this way.

Answer (score 2):

HypoVereinsbank (member of UniCredit group), a few savings banks ("Sparkasse") and VR Banks offer cash (bill) deposit machines.

However, it can take a few business days until the deposit is credited to your checking account, which has to be with the same bank.

Google for "Bargeldeinzahlungsautomat" (=cash deposit machine).

As Duffbeer stated correctly, HSBC Trinkaus which is the German arm of the HSBC group does not operate any ATMs in Germany. In addition they do not share the same bank accounts. So I would recommend going with the classic banks mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I know that many HSBC ATMs at branches in the US and Canada offer this service (they actually scan and shred checks as you deposit them). Perhaps they do same in Germany... but not all ATMs offer this feature.

Comment: HSBC only operates private banking for the very wealthy in Germany: http://www.hsbctrinkaus.de and it seems they don't have any own ATMs at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Sparkasse or VR Bank have them quite often. They stick out in my mind because when you make a withdrawal you have to reach in to get your money instead of it spitting it out. I'm always afraid its going to chop my hand off.